# vscode terminal showing weird character

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, bitbucket

since I updated my Git to the latest version, sometimes it will show this kind of characters when I'm typing something

[image: vscode terminal]

in this case I was only typing the word 'git'. is something wrong with my vscode or is bitbucket actually trash?

Comment: press ctrl+c a few times and see if it continues? They look like output formatting characters

Comment: @evolutionxbox nope, ctrl+c does nothing. but if I type 'clear' and press Enter, the terminal clears like normal

Comment: Those are codes to display colors in unix (Linux, MacOS, BSD, Solaris etc.). They should display the word "git" in the correct color (93 is bright yellow) if you run the command in gitbash. Unix terminals use in-band signaling (the same stdout you print to) to control terminal behavior like color, cursor position etc. Windows cmd.com/cmd.exe use API calls to do the same thing so they are incompatible. Powershell should understand it however. Make sure VSCode is using the right kind of terminal

Comment: @slebetman the colors are still correct in the first line. the problem only occurs after there's a fatal error message. this error has only started after I updated my git and bitbucket requires app password which causes the fatal error message.

Comment: Nonetheless, it's not *Git's* fault: Git has always used these escape sequences. Something about your particular command-line interpreter is causing *it* to change *its* behavior after the error. Figure out what that is, and fix that.